# RMI Reconnection Problem

Tags: java, rmi

I have a strange problem with RMI. Firstly, i started the server, then i started the client. In the first time, i can connect from the client to the server. Then i stop the client. And i attempt to re-connect the client. I can get the server stub, however when i call a method from the stub, i got a bunch of exception of "Connection Refused" . I have no firewall turn on.

My code for setting up the Server

```
public Server(String name, int port) {
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            ServerModel server = new ServerModel();
            String serverStr = "rmi://localhost:" + port + "/" + name;
            Naming.rebind(serverStr, server);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

And the code for setting up the Client

```
public Client(String serverName, int port) throws RemoteException {
        controller = new ClientController();
        view = new MainView();
        ClientRegistry.setData(ClientConstant.FRONT_CONTROLLER, controller);
        try {
            String serverStr = "rmi://localhost:" + port + "/" + serverName;
            ServerInterface serverStub = (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup(serverStr);
            ClientRegistry.setData(ClientConstant.STUB, serverStub);
            view.setFrontController(controller);
            view.display();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Show error if server is not available
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server is not available", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

And the Exception

> java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
>           java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.104

Answer (score 1):

When you call `LocateRegistry.createRegistry`, you instantiate a new RMI registry on a specific port. `Naming.rebind`, on the other hand, tries to register your object on the "default" registry, on the default port. It therefore fails, since no registry exists on the default port.

Try this instead:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
registry.rebind(serverStr, server);
```

Comment: I have made change to my code using your suggestions, however, the problem is still happened. I can normally connect to the server in the first time. However, when i quit a client and try to reconnect to the server, i got "Connection Refused" exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is exiting. Store the result of createRegistry into a static variable.